# Complex Query from several models in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, django-filter

I'm trying to query into three models. I need to get the amount products that are in the stores region location. These are my models:

```
class Store(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="user_store")
    region = models.CharField("Departamento", max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField("Ciudad", max_length=100)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Nombre del Producto", max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Product is related with user and it is related to store, what I want to do is something like this:

```
{
    "Risaralda": 1523,
    "Cundinamarca": 8541
}
```

where keys "Risaralda" and "Cundinamarca" are regions and values are the  product amount in these places

I tried something like this

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
    seller__user_store__region__in=Store.objects.filter()
    .values("region").distinct())
```

And I got products in stores regions but i need to count how many products are in every store regions

thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models import Count


Product.objects.annotate(region=F('seller__user_store__region')).annotate(num_products=Count('id')).values_list('region', 'num_products')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I also found a solution adding two lines:
```
        products = Product.objects.filter(
            seller__user_store__region__in=Store.objects.filter()\
            .values("region").distinct())\
            .annotate(place=F('seller__user_store__region'))\
            .values("place").annotate(products=Count('place')
        )
```
I liked the way that you use F, Thanks